# SQL query results are different than varibles

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to set a url parameter by using uniqid function in php, I get the unique numbers and place them in my database by useing them in a hidden input form. I try to make it so, at the start of the script $number is set to a uniqid which I placed in the hidden input so it will be posted into the database and I can use the same variable to create a href link.

The problem I'm having is that the value stored in my database is not the same as the value stored in the number variable used in the href link which renders the link useless. How do I get both the values equal is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

I have tried putting uniqid() in a function

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$homeDB = "homeDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $homeDB);

if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("failed to connect to server".$conn->connect_error);
} 
$number = uniqid();
if(isset($_POST["namn"])) {  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO information (firstname, lastname, urlID)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["namn"]."','".$_POST["efternamn"]."',
                    '".$_POST["hide"]."')";

    if($conn->query($sql)== TRUE){
        $link = "http://localhost/sqltutorial/execute.php?id=".$number;

    } else {
        echo "failed";
    }

    echo $link;
}
```

html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="home.php">
    <input type="text" name="namn"> <br>
    <input type="text" name= "efternamn"><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php $number ?>" name="hide">
    <input type="submit" >
    </form>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

I get different values on the link that is echoed and the value stored in my database ( I know this form is not secure )

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use the `$_POST['hide']` value on the link.

It would also be better to echo the link only if it has been created. 
Where you have the echo currently, it is possible to echo the `$link` variable even if it was not been created!

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$homeDB = "homeDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $homeDB);

if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("failed to connect to server".$conn->connect_error);
} 

$number = uniqid();

if(isset($_POST["namn"])) {  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO information (firstname, lastname, urlID)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["namn"]."','".$_POST["efternamn"]."',
                    '".$_POST["hide"]."')";

    if($conn->query($sql)== TRUE){
        $link = "http://localhost/sqltutorial/execute.php?id=$_POST[hide]";
        // line moved to here
        echo $link;
    } else {
        echo "failed";
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the postback runs, you also run the line `$number = uniqid();` again. So the final number which is output is not the one you placed in the hidden field.

Now, you could write

```
$link = "http://localhost/sqltutorial/execute.php?id=".$_POST["hide"];
```

and it would output the number which was passed in the POST variable.

---

Or you could just wait until the postback has happened to generate the unique ID, and use that in both the database call and the output. This saves a) a round-trip for the variable to the browser and back to the server, and b) anyone trying to tamper with the form data. So move the number creation code inside the `if`:

```
if(isset($_POST["namn"])) {
  $number = uniqid();
```

...and then replace both references to `$_POST["hide"]` with `$number` instead. You can also remove the hidden field from your form.

---

One final alternative suggestion: Do you even need to do this? I assume your database table has an auto_increment integer field as the primary key? Why not just use the value already being generated by the database as the value for your link?

```
if($conn->query($sql)== TRUE){
  $link = "http://localhost/sqltutorial/execute.php?id=".$conn->insert_id;
```

would get the auto-generated ID of the last row you inserted and use that in the link instead. See also [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

I don't see any great purpose in creating a second ID for your row (especially since uniqid() [does not promise](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to always give you a completely unique value), unless you have some specific reason?

Answer (score -1):

So, you want to create a row and redirect on that link after creating.

**Steps:**

**1)** First get the next auto increment value for this `informations` table by this function and store it in `$number`.

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'informations'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $number = $row[10];
    }
```

**2)** Now do inserting, and after insert you'll get the same autoincrement ID and do everything with that.

Hope, it will help.

**NB:** You can make a function to grab that auto Increment ID for any table also.

Comment: that is not how you get the autoincrement value from an insert.

Comment: This is an approach, you definitely can get the value ? Have you checked the code?

Comment: 1) there's a proper function for it which you run _after_ the insert (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php - this is what is recommended and used by everyone), 2) I'm far from convinced your approach (which I've never seen anyone advocate before) would work in the case of concurrent inserts...I can't see how you could guarantee to get the right ID if two people were trying to get this value at once and then insert straight afterwards. There's a high chance they both get given the same ID, which then results in a key violation error. But anyway, it's unnecessary - see 1)